# A question about induction proofs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

From all the ones I've seen, they usually involve writing a formula for P(k+1). So my question is if that's necessary. Suppose P(1) is already verified. Then based on the assumption that P(k) is true, P(k+1) is necessarily true since P(1) is true. Then set k = 1. So besides verifying a formula for P(1), what's the point of writing a formula for P(k+1) after assuming it for P(k)? It seems like the proof is already contained in the logic.

Comment: I was unable to follow the “based on the assumption that $P(k)$ is true, $P(k+1)$ is necessarily true since $P(1)$ is true” part.

Comment: Put $P(k)$: $k < 2$. Then $P(1)$ is true, but $P(2)$ is false...

Comment: You might think of induction by analogy of knocking over dominoes.  Verifying $P(1)$ is like tipping over the first domino, but you should know from experience that just because you tip over the first domino that doesn't automatically mean they all fall over... for example if the dominoes are a mile apart from eachother, knocking over the first will have nothing to do with knocking over the second. Verifying $P(k)\implies P(k+1)$ is like verifying that the dominoes are actually close enough that one being knocked over will cause the next to be knocked over too and is a necessary step.

Comment: If you prove that P(k) holds, then you are done. But you did not. Induction is a way of bypassing that

Comment: i didn't say that just P(1) is enough. I don't think you answered my question and just gave me your interpretation of induction. I want to know where my version is perhaps wrong. If P(k) is true and it is because that's a given condition. So setting k = 1 is true and by adding k to itself that's P(2). Then p(2) is true...I'm just asking why you write formulas for P(k+1) when it's already necessarily true?

Comment: @ goldname we don't prove p(k) but assume that it is true right?

Comment: @jose, isn't P(k+1) already the truth IF P(k) is true because set k = 1 and 1 is already verified to begin with

Comment: @EdonKnoul Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we want to prove $$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$  Now, it's true when $n=1$, so we suppose that it's true when $n=k,$ and try to prove it when $n=k+1.$  So, we assume that $$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... + k^2 = \frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}\tag{1}$$ and we try to deduce from that that $$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... + (k+1)^2 = \frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)}{6}.\tag{2}$$

I think you'll agree that it take more work to get from (1) to (2) than simply observing that $1=1.$  What you need to do is ask yourself, "How can I use (1) to deduce (2)?"  Well, (1) gives a formula for the first $k$ terms on the left-hand side of (2), so we can convert (2) to $$ \frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6} +(k+1)^2 = \frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)}{6}.\tag{3}$$

Now we have to prove (3), and that's straightforward algebra.  Make sure you understand how we used the assumption of (1) to aid in proving (2).  It's what induction is all about.

Comment: Why would you need to prove that n = k + 1 is true? You know the 1 term in k + 1 is true because that's P(1). So if you set k = 1 then that already makes P(2) true. Then set k = 2 then P(3) is true and so on...my question is why you would need to write( I mean that like literally just write it because it's seems unnecessary). And also why was it necessary for you to say it's true for n = 1 when it didn't seem like you used it for any good.

Comment: What do you mean by "the 1 term in $k+1$?"  $P(2)$ is $1^2+2^2 = 2\cdot 3 \cdot 5/6.$"  How is that "automatically true" because 1 = 1?  Mathematical induction isn't some cheap swindle; you actually have to prove the statements.  As to why you have to prove $P(1)$, that's the basis.  All inductive proofs start out that way.

Comment: Isn't that how induction works or am I mistakenly? P(k + 1) is automatically true only if P(k) And P(1) is true. Since P(1) can easily be verified and if you let k = 1 then wouldn't two true statement P(k) and P(1) mean that P(k + 1) is true?

Comment: No, that is not at all how induction works.  P(k+1) is a statement about the number $k+1.$  It doesn't mean "$P(1)$ is true and $P(k)$ is true", as you seem to think.  That would be written $P(1) \wedge P(k)$."

Answer (score 1):

If you prove only one or two or a finite number of cases for P you can’t conclude that P is always true.

The trick with induction is precisely to show that

- BASE CASE: P(m) is true for some value m (at least one)
- INDUCTIVE STEP: if P(k) is true then P(k+1) is true

in this way you can extend P(n) to all integers $n\ge m$.

Answer (score 0):

Let P(k) stand for any k horses are the same color.

Then P(1) is true.

According to you, since P(1) is true, then P(2) is true. Do you really believe that?

Comment: Isn't induction only used for proving a statement about the progression of natural numbers or analogies with such progressions? What does horses having the same color have to do with progression?

Comment: It's for proving P(k) where $k$ is a natural number and P(k) is a statement that is true or false for each value of $k$.

Comment: It must be true.  If it were false, that would be a horse of a different color.

Comment: @steven ok we'll all I'm trying to do is understand how induction works and it usually starts off with a reasonably derived statement. You can use logic to prove all different kinds of weird propositions. What's the point of using induction on such an obviously weird intuitive statement?

Comment: To try to get you to see what is wrong with your logic.